# No protocol handler was valid for the URL /url. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.4, load-balancing, jetty, websocket

Trying to set up a load balancer using Apache 2.4.x on Windows. 
Error:  No protocol handler was valid for the URL /path/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

Accessing webswing with websocket code deployed on jetty server.

Same configuration is working on Linux.

config file:

```
ProxyPass /path balancer://cluster/path/ timeout=600 
ProxyPassReverse /path balancer://cluster/path/ timeout=600
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyTimeout 600

<Proxy "balancer://cluster">
Require valid-user 
AuthName "ClosedProxy"
AuthType Basic
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Satisfy Any

BalancerMember ws://server1 route=1 timeout=600 
BalancerMember ws://server2 route=3 timeout=600
ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID lbmethod=byrequests
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the surface, this means you didn't load mod_proxy_wstunnel on your Windows system.

Comment: And modules proxy_balancer, proxy_http (direct requirement of wstunnel) and  lbmethod_byrequest have to be loaded.